# block the creation of multiple object of a class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

How do I limit the object of any class to one. My class looks like :

```
class Speaker
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, :type => String
end
```

I just want to let a single instance of speaker . One way would be to add a validation which would check the number of objects already present of the Speaker class. 
Is there a ruby way of doing thing ?

Comment: If you want only one speaker, does it makes sense to store it in db. I would have extracted it to a config file.

Comment: @rubish I need to allow the admin to change the value. How would I do that efficiently if I don't save it in the database ?

Comment: what about validation, as I wrote below?

Comment: @Slawosz I think that is the best thing I can do right now. Just waiting if I can find any better solution.

Answer (score 10):

How about using the [Singleton](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?RubySingleton) module?

Comment: how do I change the value . I also want the value to persist.

Comment: If it's the Admin USER changing the value, then this answer has a code smell. Otherwise see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons for lengthly debate.

Answer (score 8):

In this case I would write proper validation:

```
validate :only_one

def only_one
   errors.add(:base, "Only one Speaker can exist") if self.count > 0 
end
```

Comment: This will fail if the record already exists and you're updating it.

Comment: Good point, but you can write:
validate :only_one, :on => :create

Comment: ``NoMethodError: undefined method `count` for #<Speaker:0x28f18e1d>`` - `self` in the context of a validation method is an instance, so `self.count` needs to be changed to `Speaker.count` or `self.class.count`

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using a class/module that is tailored to storing configuration values rather rolling your own on top of a vanilla ActiveRecord model.

I use a old copy of the [rails-settings](https://github.com/Squeegy/rails-settings) plugin with some custom modification (it still works just fine in Rails 3). There are also a number of variant offerings listed on Github, so feel free to look and take your pick.

Answer (score 3):

Why not provide a default Speaker object, and just not provide controller actions for create or delete?

Seems the simplest solution by far.

Answer (score 3):

### I see you're using [Mongoid](http://mongoid.org/)

The functionality you request is not available using [mongoid validations](http://mongoid.org/docs/validation.html).

Therefore, you will need to write your own. `before_validation` is a [supported callback](http://mongoid.org/docs/callbacks.html) and chained `Speaker.all.count` methods [are available to your model](http://mongoid.org/docs/querying/finders.html).

```
class Speaker
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, :type => String
  before_validation(:ensure_has_only_one_record, :on => :create)
  def ensure_has_only_one_record
    self.errors.add :base, "There can only be one Speaker." if Speaker.all.count > 0
  end
end
```

#### However, the [best practice is to put all key/value settings in a single table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306412/rails-3-application-user-settings-best-practice).

Answer (score 2):

Using the Singleton module and a little overriding of its methods, I believe this works and it's thread safe (on ruby 1.8):

```
class Speaker 

  include Singleton
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, :type => String

  @@singleton__instance__ = nil
  @@singleton__mutex__ = Mutex.new

  def self.instance
    return @@singleton__instance__ if @@singleton__instance__
    @@singleton__mutex__.synchronize {
      return @@singleton__instance__ if @@singleton__instance__
      @@singleton__instance__ = self.first
      @@singleton__instance__ ||= new()
    }
    @@singleton__instance__
  end

  def destroy
    @@singleton__mutex__.synchronize {
      super
      @@singleton__instance__ = nil
    }
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Back in Ruby 1.8 [that was not the case](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4412037).