# Using hash values in Rails config settings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration

I'm looking for a best-practice approach to using hash-type values in Rails config settings.

I wanted an Heroku-friendly solution like [**Figaro**](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro)- but it [doesn't allow hashes](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro/issues/40) in the YAML file.

Comment: does this help?  do you mean user config setting? http://quickleft.com/blog/simple-rails-app-configuration-settings

Comment: or this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306412/rails-3-application-user-settings-best-practice

Comment: @dax- not really- the first example doesn't offer any solution for Heroku except manually feeding in the config values at the command line, which obviates the YAML file and so isn't a solution - and the second is for storing user settings not app config settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up rolling our own, similar to Figaro but with support for nested values, multiple files, and placeholders. It's pretty awesome: **[snappconfig](https://github.com/ykessler/snappconfig#snappconfig)**!